# Multithreading with QString

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm approaching to the multithreads world.
I've a question about QString and multithreads application.

My main application class is:

```
MyGeneralClass{
    public:
    std::vector< QString > hpg_lines;
    .
    .
    .

};
```

My class for multithread looks like this:

```
class MyTread:public QThread{
    private:
    QString qstr_;
    MyGeneralClass *gen_;
    .
    .
};
```

Each thread write something in its qstr object (a big amout of strings) and at the end of the thread will copy it on the vector hpg_lines of the main class.
Can I do this or I can occur in some data lost?
thank you for your help

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html

Comment: Not sure if you are falling into that trap, but note that `QThread` is thread controller. It is not the thread. So it would probably be best, if you put any variables modified by the thread, and any code you want to run in the thread into a separate class. Also note, that if you want a Qt event loop running the thread (so you can connect signal's to slots in the thread), you generalliy should not subclass `QThread`, because there is no reason to (and many unnecessary ways you can screw things up if you do it).

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge std::vector is not thread safe (for reading and writing). Since you need concurent access to shared data structure the most naive and easy solution whould be http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html . Declare a new mutex and then use:

```
    your_mutex.lock();
    do your stuff on the data structure;
    your_mutex.unlock();
```

Make sure though that your_mutex is also the same resource between the threads and not each thread with one mutex. That means that mutex should probably be glboal variable or be passed to each thread.

Comment: From a software engineering point of view it makes more sense to create your own `threadsafe_vector` that is basically just a wrapper around a `vector` which creates a `std::lock_guard` first to lock a `std::mutex` (your version breaks if an exception is thrown).

Comment: Thank you very much. I add to MyGeneralClass a private object QMutex accesible from all the threads by the pointer  *gen_. Each time I operate on the vector I add lock and unlock mutex functions. Now my code works as I expected!

Comment: @Mike `vector` has a lot of member functions, redeclaring them all is not really feasible. I would just add the functions when I need them and usually end up with only 5 or 10. Alternatively you can expose the `vector` and expect the caller not to keep a reference past the lock, but that can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way would be that the result would be passed to the controlling thread and that thread can copy the result to the vector.  This way the vector is not accessed from multiple threads.  In Qt, this can be done by a [queued connection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

Answer (score 0):

Please use mutex.lock() and mutex.unlock() functions when you are going to write string to qstr and add to to vector hpg_lines; (mutex is an object of Qmutex class)

for example

```
mutex.lock()
    write string to qstr;
    add qstr to hpg_lines;
mutex.unlock();
```

This way the other thread will not be allowed to modify qstr or hpg_lines;

Thanks 
Sajeesh